# model structs for many to many relationship using std

Tags: mysql, go, many-to-many

I'm trying to learn go and I want to create a many to many relationship between a post and a tag. A tag can belong to many posts and a post can have many tags. I am using the standard library using the mysql drive (github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql)

Here's my code:

post.go

```
package main

type post struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Content string `json:"content"`
    Tags: Tag `json:"tags"`
}
```

tag.go

```
package main

type tag struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Posts: Post `json:"posts"`
}
```

Is this the correct way to structure this many to many relationship?

Cheers

Comment: That code won't compile - I assume it's more 'pseudo-code'

Comment: Yeah its pseudo-code. I am just planning my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of modifications to consider:

1. Keep your type names consistent (`post` vs. `Post` for example)
2. I think you were going for a slice of Tags and a slice of Posts, so I updated the syntax for that.
3. One significant question you'll need to answer; do you need/want your structures to be stored in memory with single structs for each item?  If so you'll probably want to consider using slices of pointers to Tag and Post instead (`[]*Post` and `[]*Tag` for example), but popular ORM libraries don't strictly need that (for example gorm: http://jinzhu.me/gorm/associations.html#many-to-many).

Example code:

```
type Post struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Content string `json:"content"`
    Tags []Tag `json:"tags"`
}

type Tag struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Posts []Post `json:"posts"`
}
```

Comment: The benefit of using the pointers would be that I could update the value at the pointer, otherwise using `Tag` or `Post` would just be read-only. Is that correct?

I was going to use gorm but from reading online the general consensus I got was its better to learn go using just the standard library.

Comment: Yes, if I understand you correctly, using pointers would make it easier for you to modify the structs "in-place".  I think using the standard library and the native language as much as possible is good, but in the case of Object-to-Relational mapping there aren't as many native examples, and using a popular library may decrease the liklihood of edge-case errors.

Comment: Okay awesome I think I get it, thanks so much! I am going to continue with the standard library for now. Hopefully it all works out